# Problems in customizing the macOS menu bar with MenuSystemUIServer

Tags: macos, sh, plist, dotfiles, macos-sierra

In my menu bar, I'd like to **hide** *TimeMachine*, *Volume*, *Battery*, *User*, *Clock* and **show** just *Bluetooth*, and *Airport*.

I tried to customize it with an `sh` script:

```
for domain in ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.systemuiserver.*; do
  defaults write "${domain}" dontAutoLoad -array \
    "/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/TimeMachine.menu" \
    "/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Volume.menu" \
    "/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Battery.menu" \
    "/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/User.menu" \
    "/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Clock.menu"
done

defaults write com.apple.systemuiserver menuExtras -array \
  "/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Bluetooth.menu" \
  "/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/AirPort.menu"
```

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to make it work. I obviously `killall SystemUIServer`, logged out, rebooted.. No luck. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're trying to do this from the command line? Command-dragging the icons off the menu bar works pretty well.

Comment: @Spiff It's part of a dotfile I'm working on.

Comment: dotfile as in a shell startup script? Are you saying you want to reset it this way every time you start a shell session?

Comment: @Spiff bootstrap of new machines only https://dotfiles.github.io